# Add a little more flexibility when searching closed questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search

I wanted to do a little cleanup in Gaming, and set off to search old closed questions other than exact duplicates, which would be candidates for deletion.

I was unable to find a way to specifically search for that, as searching for `closed:1` doesn't let me exclude the duplicates which I don't want to delete.

The only option I had was to click on every result to see in the question what the close reason was.

Could we have an advanced search option, or a section in the mod tools, that would allow me to search all closed questions that are not duplicates?

Comment: It is possible to see which questions were closed as duplicates because the first words shown in search page for the question are, "Possible Duplicate:" I agree; it would be preferable to have a list of questions that are not duplicates, rather than scanning the search page to avoid the questions I don't really want.

Comment: @lunboks, I realized I can sort to get the worst ones

Comment: @JuanManuel Well, if you're talking about a site with more than 5k closed questions, that won't really work, unless mods have a higher limit for search results.

Comment: @lunboks, I guess I can start from the bottom and then more will appear... anyway, be sure to cast your delete votes too! :)

Answer (score 4):

The [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) is perfect for a bit of spring cleaning. You can exclude duplicates, no trouble, and add as much complexity as you want. Of course, it's not really live data, and less convenient than an on-site tool, but whatcha gonna do.

I wrote [a query for deletion candidates](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/64285/closed-questions-that-wont-be-auto-deleted-within-a-month-excluding-duplicates) that sounds sorta like what you want. It lists all closed questions, sorted by score and post date, excluding duplicates and questions that will disappear on their own anyway (i.e., those at -1 or lower with no answers).

<sup>(It times out on SO, because SO's backlog of old closed questions is beyond the help of any mortal man.)</sup>

Comment: Nice, will try it (though I'd prefer the filter built-in (the first question is one I deleted 5 days ago))

Comment: @JuanManuel Well, the latest data dump happened *just* before the ITG purge, so those tend to get in the way a bit.

Comment: @lunboks you can get it to work for SO if you remove the magic [Post Link] and [User Link] fields. [See my forked version](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/64598/68352/closed-questions-that-wont-be-auto-deleted-within-a-month-excluding-duplicates)

Comment: This is a nice solution, unfortunately the Data Explorer is not available for beta sites. So there would still be a significant advantage to an internal solution.

Answer (score 2):

This has been implemented at some point, we now have a `duplicate:yes/no` search operator.

E.g. `closed:yes duplicate:no` will give questions closed as off topic, but not as duplicates.

[Example on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes+duplicate%3Ano).