# Interface for questions who were closed and their 2-day grace period for deletion has expired

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools

In an effort to contribute to cleaning up questions on SO, I'd like to go back to questions that were closed more than two days ago and vote to delete ones that are useless. My motivation is that I'd be targeting questions I voted to close earlier, but could not vote to delete since I do not have 20k rep.

I searched the 10k tools to find an interface that will only show me questions that I have the ability to vote to delete, and didn't find anything promising. Ideally I'd like to be able to filter by tag as well, but this is not a necessity.

I think the easiest way to do something like this would be to integrate it within search, with a command like `candelete:1`, which would save having to modify any existing interfaces.

I don't believe such functionality exists, but if it does, great!

Comment: It looks like the [delete "tools" tab](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?s=1&tab=delete&daterange=today) doesn't actually provide this functionality.  Questions you can delete are the ones that *aren't* faded, but they only appear once someone else has cast the first vote.

Comment: In addition, I'd like the ability to filter out locked questions.  I don't need to see those when I'm evaluating posts to be deleted after being closed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add a little more flexibility when searching closed questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126389/add-a-little-more-flexibility-when-searching-closed-questions)

Comment: @JQAn - It's not quite the same, as that doesn't take into account the current user's privileges on whether or not they can delete a question.

Comment: Ok, disregard my vote, [related then](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126389/add-a-little-more-flexibility-when-searching-closed-questions) (although it could be included in the original request) -- I just want it to be implemented ;)