# Add a new review task for deleting closed questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, closed-questions, vote-to-delete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we get some more review queues - questions with delete votes, recently closed etc.?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148204/can-we-get-some-more-review-queues-questions-with-delete-votes-recently-close)

There are way too many closed questions that should be deleted and [the current way to do it is very inconvenient](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126389/add-a-little-more-flexibility-when-searching-closed-questions).

Obviously only not-as-duplicate closed questions should appear in the list, and perhaps they should have some kind of date filter and only show questions closed N days/hours ago (the usual waiting time for non-urgent posts is 48 hours).

Comment: related: [Can we get some more review queues - questions with delete votes, recently closed etc.?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148204/can-we-get-some-more-review-queues-questions-with-delete-votes-recently-close)

Comment: Currently, only 10k+ users can vote to delete, so maybe that should be under /tools, not /review.

Comment: @bfavaretto only users with 3k+ can vote to close, and we have a review task for closing.

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe of @ChrisF's question, he's not asking for this new task -- he's talking about how to use the list of questions with delete votes to feed tasks for improving questions.

Comment: I think I'd modify this into a "delete it before it's too late" review task. It should look for closed questions (whether they have delete votes or not) that have posts with 3 or more votes and have not passed the 60 day mark yet. These questions are primary targets for review, and deleting the crap ones quickly will prevent users from keeping ill-gotten reputation, while also allowing users to reopen any that might deserve to be reopened. Those posts which are closest to the 60-day mark should be displayed first.